# how do I remove phpunit from pear correctly

Tags: phpunit, composer-php, pear

So I have a problem, because at the moment I have phpunit in a 3.7 version installled through pear. Now, I wanted to upgrade this, but in the documentation they recommend installing it globally through composer. I've done this, it installs the current newest version(5.3) but if i type **phpunuit -version** it says that I have installed a version 3.7. Now, I can't somehow remove this package from pear, it says that **phpunit can not be found**, although I can see the phpunit files in the pear directory. If I do **pear list**, phpunit doesn't show up, so I'm not able to delete this package. Is there a way to overrite the pear phpunit package with that one, that I'm pulling in with composer?

Answer (score 0):

`pear list` only lists packages from the default channel, which is `pear.php.net` unless you configured it otherwise.

To see *all* packages, use the `-a` flag as described in `pear help list`:

```
$ pear list -a
Installed packages, channel __uri:
==================================
(no packages installed)

Installed packages, channel doc.php.net:
========================================
Package Version    State
pman    2015.06.19 stable

Installed packages, channel pear.geshi.org:
===========================================
Package Version  State
geshi   1.0.8.10 stable

Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package             Version State
Archive_Tar         1.4.0   stable
Console_CommandLine 1.2.0   stable
Console_Getopt      1.4.1   stable
Net_LDAP2           2.2.0   stable
PEAR                1.10.1  stable
PEAR_Manpages       1.10.0  stable
PHP_CodeSniffer     2.5.0   stable
Stream_Var          1.1.0   stable
Structures_Graph    1.1.1   stable
VersionControl_Git  0.4.4   alpha
XML_Util            1.3.0   stable

Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
(no packages installed)
```